# ERROR: for traefik Container "c76ca635f085" is unhealthy. Sitecore docker installation Issue

Tags: docker

I was trying to setting up Sitecore Helix Example, getting issue during docker-compose
`ERROR: for traefik  Container "c76ca635f085" is unhealthy.`
looked more about the issue by looking at the logs
`"Status": "unhealthy", "FailingStreak": 8, "Log": [{ "Start": "2020-12-25T12:12:41.3339915+05:30", "End": "2020-12-25T12:13:10.3143364+05:30", "ExitCode": 1, "Output": "http://localhost:80/healthz/ready - ServiceUnavailable\r\n"}]`

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

From the screenshot there are unhealthy status containers with 80/tcp ports.
So to make sure i changed port 80 with 82 in file https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/blob/master/examples/helix-basic-aspnetcore/docker-compose.override.yml

There is no custom config changes i have done, just changed port as mentioned port were already in use.
https://sitecore.github.io/Helix.Examples/install.html

Installation has been done and i can also see docker image is running.
I was also able to see Sitecore live page using instance ip but not able to logged in Sitecore instance

Tried command also as below
`dotnet sitecore login --cm https://cm.basic-company-aspnetcore.localhost/ --auth https://id.basic-company-aspnetcore.localhost/ --allow-write true`

got error as below
`Logging in to Sitecore. You should see a browser window open shortly. Error connecting to https://id.basic-company-aspnetcore.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.`
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KFvQ.png

Comment: try run the clean.ps1 under the /docker folder

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The traefik container depends on the health of CM, CD. What I suggest you first check the health of these containers (use the command "docker ps"). After running this command if you find out the CM or CD container is "unhealthy". To know the real error you need to inspect the container (CM and CD) (use the command "docker container inspect 'your container id'".). Get the IP address(it will be at the end in the network section something like

```
"Networks": {
                "public-health-ontario_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "cm",
                        ""
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "",
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    **"IPAddress": "172.32.127.138",**
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": 
                }
            }
```

and then go browser and hit URL like "http://172.32.127.138/healthz/ready"

Answer (score 4):

If you run Docker from a machine where IIS is installed you need to stop IIS for Traefick to work correctly. Cmd: `iisreset /stop`

Answer (score 0):

If still error exist;
Please try run below commends in Power shell one by one.

1. docker-compose stop
2. docker-compose down
3. iisreset /stop
4. docker-compose up -d

Hope this will solve Error to bringing up the project.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it requires treafik image re-downloading (if iisreset /stop does not help) by removing such image from local storage, so it will download this image again next time:
[image]